# Android webview CreatePlatformSocket() failed: Machine is not on the network

Tags: android, android-webview

At first connecting to wifi network of iot device programmatically at one point iot device will disconnect that time manually connecting to different wifi network after this configuration change while loading the webview always throws this error

E/GPUAUX: [AUX]GuiExtAuxCheckAuxPath:663: Null anb

E/chromium: [ERROR:socket_posix.cc(96)] CreatePlatformSocket() failed: Machine is not on the network (64)

webview onerror callback returns

error.description -> net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

error.code -> -1 / -2

But after relaunching its working fine